# Firebase SMS verification code request fails with unknown status 17499 Firebase app check token invalid, too many attemps

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I encountered an error while attempting to initiate phone authentication with Firebase.

This is part of my logs

> W/LocalRequestInterceptor(29316): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.

> E/FirebaseAuth(29316): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Firebase App Check token is invalid.

- SHA1 and SHA256 have been added to the Firebase configuration
- I enable Google Play Integrity under the Google Cloud project
- I enabled Play Integrity under the Firebase app check
- And this is how I have setup the app check

```dart
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
  webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
  androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The AndroidProvider.debug should generate a debug token in debug console of your app for use in firebase. Place it in the Apps section of App Check. For more information and reference check:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider